# Vue Router History Mode with PWA in Offline Mode

Tags: vue.js, service-worker, vue-router, progressive-web-apps, offline-caching

To get history mode working with Vue-Router you need to return the contents of your main page when trying to access a route that doesn't exist.  For example when you visit `mypwa.com/route1` your server checks if there is a resource at `route1` and if there isn't, it returns the contents that is found at `mypwa.com/` (but without redirecting you).  This is great and works when you're online, but it requires your server to do the actual re-routing.

If you have a PWA that's meant to work offline, you need this re-routing to work without the server being available.
The problem is this: visiting `mypwa.com/` when you're offline works.  After loading it you can then navigate to `mypwa.com/route1` from inside the app.  However, if you try to navigate directly to `mypwa.com/route1` whilst offline you will get a 404 error because `mypwa.com/route1` is not cached, only `/` is cached.
I suppose this means that you need some kind of fallback clause in your service worker?  Does anyone know of a way to achieve this?   Is there a common way to do it with sw-precache-webpack-plugin?

Answer (score 10):

You need to set the [navigateFallback](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-webpack-plugin#generateSW-navigateFallback) option in your `vue.config.js` file:

```js
pwa: {
  workboxOptions: {
    navigateFallback: 'index.html'
  }
}
```

It will automatically add the necessary code to your service worker:

```js
workbox.routing.registerNavigationRoute(workbox.precaching.getCacheKeyForURL("index.html"));
```

I had the same problem and I found the solution here: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/717#issuecomment-382079361

Comment: "ValidationError: "navigateFallback" is not a supported parameter." in vue/cli-plugin-pwa version 4.2.3 :'(... Vue PWA currently uses Workbox v4.3.1, not sure though, if that's why it's not supported (anymore?)..

Comment: Thank you, searched hours for this!

Answer (score 7):

If your site is a single page app, you can use a `NavigationRoute` to return a specific response for all navigation requests.

```
workbox.routing.registerNavigationRoute('/single-page-app.html')
```

In my case in vue :

```
workbox.routing.registerNavigationRoute('/index.html')
```

Whenever a user goes to your site in the browser, the request for the page will be a navigation request and will be served the cached page `/single-page-app.html`.

***Note***: You should have the page cached via workbox-precaching or through your own installation step).

By default, this will respond to all navigation requests, if you want to restrict it to respond to a subset of URL’s you can use the whitelist and blacklist options to restrict which pages will match this route.

**Update: Workbox V5**

```
const handler = workbox.precaching.createHandlerBoundToURL("/index.html");

const navigationRoute = new workbox.routing.NavigationRoute(handler);

workbox.routing.registerRoute(navigationRoute);
```

Comment: where do you add this line please?