# Vue Cli 404 on wwwroot/index.html error using PWA

Tags: vue.js, progressive-web-apps, vue-cli-3

I've just moved an app over to the vue cli, but i'm having an issue with getting the PWA to work. When its trying to load it up theres an console error

Uncaught (in promise) bad-precaching-response: bad-precaching-response :: [{"url":"/wwwroot/index.html?**WB_REVISION**=xxxxxxx","status":404}]

Thing is i'm not really sure where this error is commminng from. The actual sire loads fine, and all the asserts are ok, but thw PWA index.html seems to be loading from the wrong place. its in /index.html not /wwwrooot/html. I'm not sure why its trying to load from here. This is what the vue.config looks like

```
pwa: {
    name: 'app Portal',
    themeColor: '#CC0001',
    msTileColor: '#CC0001',
    appleMobileWebAppCapable: 'yes',
    appleMobileWebAppStatusBarStyle: 'black',
    workboxOptions: {
        exclude: /\.cshtml$/,
        /*
            docs: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/lifecycle#skip_the_waiting_phase
            a new service worker does not serve pages until the old one releases control
            this is called the waiting phase

            skipWaiting means the new one immediately takes control. this may cause issues with people still using your application
        */
        skipWaiting: true,
    },
},
```

``

Any ideas why the PWA seems to be loading the index.html from the wrong place?

Answer (score 0):

I use the pwa webpack config `navigatefallback` to fix this issue please see: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-webpack-plugin#generateSW-navigateFallback

Also pwa can fail with history mode enabled on the vue Router:

here are some questions that i think will get you in the right direction:

[PWA doesn't load when router is in history mode (Vue CLI 3 based project)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53805608/pwa-doesnt-load-when-router-is-in-history-mode-vue-cli-3-based-project)

and

[Vue Router History Mode with PWA in Offline Mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49963982/vue-router-history-mode-with-pwa-in-offline-mode)